# Thinking Sphinx: Failed index on double precision field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thinking-sphinx

Trying to add an index to a field containing a ruby float (represented as double precision in Postgres), I get the following error when rebuilding the index:

```
indexing index 'user_core'...
ERROR: index 'user_core': sql_range_query: ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
LINE 1: ..._name_sort", COALESCE("users"."average_rating", '') AS "av...
```

The line I added in the model that caused this error to appear is as follows:

```
indexes :average_rating, :sortable => true, :type => :float
```

Been unable to find anyone having trouble indexing floats by googling. Is this a bug, or am I missing something obvious as usual? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because it is not a string based column, try this:

```
has :average_rating, :sortable => true, :type => :float
```

To read more about the differences between "has" and "indexes" read this: 
http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/sphinx_basics.html

Comment: Thanks Simon. I just realised this was just me being an idiot and fixed it myself, and now came here to update my question. :)

Comment: Also: no need for `:sortable => true` - it's an attribute, it's always sortable.